# Cube Creation in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, olap-cube

I am learning creating Cubes and Now I know How to create cubes.
But Still I am struggling with time dimensions and other aspects of cubes,making cubes offline and usage of cubes in excel dashboards.

Could somebody suggest me Practical based simple tutorials for cubes ?
so that I can feel confident in cubes.

Thanks in advance.

Rahul Kumar Singh

Comment: [pcteach.me](http://www.pcteach.me)

Comment: Thanks, It seems cool. I will look into it. However I am seeing tutorial is based on Sql server 2008 R2. How this one is different from  Sql server 2005. Will the soluions on this site will work on SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice little intro here:

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2008/building-cubes-with-ssas/

You could also try http://www.ssas-info.com/ for some good background and useful tips.